# What is a sub-expression in C?

Tags: c, expression

What is sub expression in C? I thought combination of smaller expression is subexpression
eg: `a*(b+C/d)/20`

`b+c/d` is subexpression is it correct?
 or alone `c/d` is subexpression ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sub-expression is *not* just any part of a larger expression.

Consider:

```
2 * 3 + 4 * 5
```

Here `3+4*5` is *not* a sub-expression.

The full expression parses as

```
(2 * 3) + (4 * 5)
```

and so the direct sub-expressions are `2*3` and `4*5`.

Each of those again parse as compositions of smaller things, with `2*3` composed of the sub-expressions `2` and `3`, and with `4*5` composed of the sub-expressions `4` and `5`.

These sub-expressions of sub-expressions are indirect sub-expressions of the original full expression, so that in total it has these sub-expressions: `2*3`, `4*5`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`.

While e.g. `3+4*5` is *not* a sub-expression.

In summary, a **sub-expression** is an argument to an operator or function, and such an argument expression can itself have sub-expressions.

---

Regarding your example

```
a*(b+C/d)/20
```

and your concrete questions

> `b+c/d` is subexpression is it correct? or alone `c/d` is subexpression ?

Yes, and yes (modulo uppercase/lowercase typo).

However, for example, here `b+C` is not a sub-expression.

Comment: Trying to understand why b+C is not a sub-expression. Is it not an argument that is passed to the division operator?

Comment: @codingManiac: the expression `b+C/d` is parsed as `b+(C/d)`, due to the grammar of C++. A simplified way to view that is that `/` has **higher precedence** than `+`, and you can find operator precedence tables everywhere. However, it's worth noting that the C++ standard only specifies the grammar, from which precedence is deduced, and that the simpler precedence view breaks down in certain situations, e.g. for the `?:` choice operator. The only common programming language I know that doesn't effectively have precedence for arithmetic operators, is old Smalltalk.

Answer (score 4):

> what is sub expression in c.i thought combination of smaller expression is subexpression

Yes. You thought correct.
*A **sub-expression** is a part of an expression that is by itself a **correct expression**.*

Sometimes a sub-expression is a **constant**, like `20` here. `/20` is not a correct expression itself hence it can't be a sub-expression.
[In general](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119343):

> a subexpression is a part of an expression that corresponds to a subtree in the parse tree -- that is, some node in the parse tree plus all of its descendants. The subexpression is a proper subexpression if it is not the entire expression.

To answer your specific questions:

> b+c/d is sub-expression is it correct?

Yes.

> or alone c/d is subexpression ?

Yes. `a`, `b`, `C`, `d`, `20`, `b+C/d` and `a*(b+C/d)` are all sub-expressions.

Comment: In a well-known quirk of the C grammar, in the constant `-20`, `20` is a subexpression.

Comment: @PascalCuoq; Added a new, more general, definition for you :0. BTW, I hope `-` sign is unary `-` here.

Answer (score 4):

A sub expression is any smaller unit in an expression, so **`C/d`** and **`b+C/d`** both are sub-expressions,

Whereas a unit here is a combination of two operands and an operator in between.
**Example,**

`C/d` is a unit, and so is `(b+C/d)`
note that in `(b+C/d)`, `C/d` will be executed first after that `(b+C/d)` will be a unit.

Also, **`a*(b+C/d)`** is a sub-expression.

and adding **`/20`** to the rest of the expression will be complete expression, so that will not be a sub-expression.

In other words we can say that in an expression, all smaller expressions contained in the complete expression are sub-expressions except the expression executed in the last(order of execution depends upon the priorities of operators).

Comment: I think you mean “smaller”. Using “smallest” makes it appear as you are saying the opposite of what you are trying to say.

Comment: Note: `/d)/20` is not a subexpression.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes because that will be evaluated in the last and that will also be in the last part of the expression, and if added will be the whole expression.

Comment: "any smaller unit" might make sense, but in order for it to make sense the term "unit" must be explained (otherwise it's full circularity)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have edited my answer please suggest any more editions if think they are necessary.

Comment: @AnkurKumawat: Well the word "here" in the new text means that it's an explanation *by example*, and that's fine, as I see it. It probably won't hurt to add a "more in general", about e.g. unary operators and function calls. But it may not necessarily be more clear either.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for your suggestion, i have improved my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that
>   specifies a computation. An expression can result in a value and can
>   cause side effects. [§5.1]

So, `b+c/d` and `c/d` both are expressions. Even, `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and `20` are expressions.